# How to solve this specific SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have post 3 Tables structure like this Course,Students,CourseAllot with Data here i need how to multiple row combine single row.How to show the based on the name concatenate and show them

```
Create Table Course 
( 
CourseId int Primary key Identity(1,1), 
CourseName Varchar(50) 
) 
Insert into Course values('C#') 
Insert into Course values('Asp.net') 
Insert into Course values('Sqlserver') 
Insert into Course values('MySql') 

Create Table Students 
( 
StudentId int Primary key identity(1,1), 
StudentName varchar(30) 
) 
Insert into Students values('John') 
Insert into Students values('David') 
Insert into Students values('Hendry') 
Insert into Students values('Smith') 
Insert into Students values('Watson') 



Create Table CourseAllot 
( 
AllotId int Primary key identity(1,1), 
CourseId int, 
StudentId int 
) 

Insert into CourseAllot values (1,1) 
Insert into CourseAllot values (1,1) 
Insert into CourseAllot values (2,1) 
Insert into CourseAllot values (1,2) 
Insert into CourseAllot values (3,4) 
Insert into CourseAllot values (3,5)
```

I need Output this

```
Sno Course Name Student Name 
1   C#  John,Hendry,David 
2   Asp.net John 
3   Sqlserver   Smith,WatSon
```

Comment: Have you started writing something in SQL? All you have to do is, Select StudentName and CourseName with a GroupBy(CourseId) with joining tables. Which part you are facing problem with?

Comment: what technology are you using to access the database? entity framework?

Comment: Is it MySql or SQL Server?, based on your tags its both...

Answer (score 0):

if you are in sqlserver use bellow query

```
    with cte(courseName,c)
    as
    (select courseName,c= studentname from  CourseAllot 
    inner join Course on CourseAllot.CourseId=Course.CourseId 
    inner join Students on Students.StudentId=CourseAllot.StudentId  
    group by courseName,studentname
    ) 

    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by courseName) as rowno, courseName,
    stuff((select ','+c from cte t where t.courseName=t2.courseName 
for xml path('')),1,1,'') as StudentName  from cte t2 group by t2.courseName
```